# Determining modulation by spectrum

Tags: modes, signal-identification

Is it feasible to determine what sort of modulation is used for a given signal by looking at the spectrum / FFT?  Does software like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely identify many of them by eye, have a look at:

http://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Signal_Identification_Guide

As for software that does it automatically, I'm not sure anything like that exists. If you find something, please let us know.

Comment: I use that site sometimes myself.  I am wondering how much of a 'science' this kind of identification is, and if it is feasible to use or write software that does it, and how accurate such software can be.